# Google Email Markup Invoice type not showing up in calendar

Tags: html, email, google-calendar-api, schema.org, google-schemas

I had tried several methods but no progress. Here is my script for invoice markup.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
    "@context": "http://schema.org/Invoice",
    "@type": "Invoice",
    "description": "August 2018 Invoice Pending",
    "url": "www.abc.com",
    "accountId": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-1234",
    "potentialaction": {
      "url": "www.xyz.com",
      "@type": "PayAction"
    },
    "paymentDue": "2018-09-08",
    "minimumPaymentDue": {
      "@type": "PriceSpecification",
      "price": "1000.00"
    },
    "totalPaymentDue": {
      "@type": "PriceSpecification",
      "price": "2000.00"
    },
    "paymentStatus": "payment due",
    "provider": {
      "@type": "Organization",
      "name": "XYZ"
      }
}
</script>
```

I am able to receive the mail but it doesn't get automatically add to my google calendar.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this doesn't add up as an event to your calendar. It will only add an embedded information about your payment in your email.

[image]

As shown above from an image in Google Documents, this shows an Invoice email in Google Inbox.

You can try using [event reservation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/event-reservation#basic_event_reminder_without_a_ticket) schema, this will automatically add an event to your calendar.